# How to change the font of a URL from \ttfamily to Euclid?

Tags: fonts, urls

I would like to include a clickable URL in a text written in LaTeX. For that I included the package `hyperref`. The result obtained by `\url` gives a clickable link written in `\ttfamily` (the default font). My question is how to set the font for `\url` so that I can obtain a clickable link written in the font "Euclid" rather than `\ttfamily`.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\url{http://stackoverflow.com/}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Is it this one: [Euclid Regular](http://www.azfonts.de/load_font/euclid.html)?

Comment: @Speravir Yes! This is the font on which Latex documents are produced. But for url I get a sort of ttfamily font. My question is how to change this font into Euclid! Thank you!

Comment: You don't need the Euclid font; just type `\urlstyle{rm}` in your document preamble (after having loaded `hyperref`).

Comment: @egreg Thank you! I used this but the link is non clickable! even if I loaded hyperref.

Answer (score 2):

In general: `hyperref` loads package `url` in background. So to change the font the right command is `\urlstyle{…}` (default is `tt` for teletype, i.e. `\ttfamily`), cf. manual of `url`.

Since you did not provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) I suppose you used the truetype font [Euclid Regular](http://www.azfonts.de/load_font/euclid.html) (a free font), which has to be set with `fontspec`, and the TeX file must be compiled with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{euclid.ttf} % if properly installed "\setmainfont{Euclid}" is preferred
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % just for some dummy text
\usepackage{hyperref} % loads "url" in background
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % for the example
\begin{document}
\kant[50]
\bigskip

\url{http://stackoverflow.com/} -- \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162164/}

\urlstyle{rm}
\url{http://stackoverflow.com/} -- \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162164/}

\bigskip

\kant[51]
\end{document}
```

Because for the test I did not install `euclid.ttf` in the fonts folder of my system I had to give the filename in `\setmainfont` instead of the preferred fontname (`Euclid`).

Comment: The Euclid font is just a clone of Computer Modern.

Comment: @egreg: I didn’t know, though the glyphs looked very familiar. So everything would work without loading an additional font here …

Comment: @Speravir Thank you for your answer. I think that I have to use the package url, then \urlstyle{same} and just write \url{http://mp0806.cineca.it/icfd.php} and all is going well! a

Comment: @Strömungsmechanik: For a clickable link you will need `hyperref`, and this package loads itself `url`. But read, waht egreg wrote: You do not need at all “Euclid”. Just leave out the loading of `fontspec` and the `\setmainfont` line, because then the default is taken, and this is “Computer Modern Roman”.

Comment: @Strömungsmechanik: You were tricked by automatism. Yes writing `\url{http://mp0806.cineca.it/icfd.php}` should work and worked here in my test.